# NoMethodError when doing vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

I'm working on an `Ubuntu 14.04` machine and using Vagrant for the first time so please bear with me.

I'm trying to do `vagrant up`, but I'm getting this error message:

```
ricardo@mymachine:~/workspace/myproject$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'debian/jessie64'...
...
...
...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] Setting hostname...
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] Running provisioner: file...
[default] Running provisioner: shell...
[default] Forcing shutdown of VM...
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'file' provisioner...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
/usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/shell/provisioner.rb:61:in `quote_and_escape': undefined method `gsub' for 1:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/shell/provisioner.rb:14:in `block in provision'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/shell/provisioner.rb:14:in `map'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/provisioners/shell/provisioner.rb:14:in `provision'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:89:in `run_provisioner'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:283:in `hook'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:74:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:74:in `block in call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:65:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:48:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/batch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you modified the vagrantfile, anything for provisioner?

Comment: No, I haven't touched the vagrantfile.

Comment: can you detail on Vagrant, ruby and VirtualBox versions ? there might be some incompatibility - vagrant 1.8+, virtualBox 5.x+ and ruby 1.9+ should work